# Phone is not booting up when mempry card is loaded

Tags: 8.1, storage, nokia-lumia-620, developer-preview

My phone is not booting up when memory card is inserted. Issue is started from last month. I did check disk, but still issue is there.

Comment: What phone do you have? Have you tried formatting the memory card? Have you tried with other memory cards?

Comment: Lumia 620. I can't format the card, have something important things in it.

Comment: Can you confirm which build you're on, as you've tagged this as [tag:developer-preview]

Comment: As of today, I'm at very latest build.

Comment: Can you backup your files on a PC?

Comment: @Thomas, Will try that if there's no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back up and did a format. SD card is working fine and no issues so far.